# How to see manual for god-mode and other packages?

Tags: manual

I installed god-mode and I can't see any manuals to learn how to use it. Also how do I enter insert mode? god-mode is unusable without it

Comment: Welcome to emacs SE!  Please ask one discrete question per post, rather than multiple ones.

Answer (score 3):

It's up to individual package developers to provide a manuals for their programs, and how they wish to provide them. Godmode doesn't appear to install a manual, so you won't find anything in the Emacs help/info system. It is documented on its github page: https://github.com/chrisdone/god-mode